# Capture "replies=all" for a User Stream und Phirehose in PHP

Tags: php, twitter-streaming-api, phirehose

This a simple question, but I wasn't able to find an answer thus far.

I use the Phirehose library (lib/UserstreamPhirehose.php) to capture the user stream in real time (class MyUserConsumer extends UserstreamPhirehose and I process the enqueueStatus() function).

It all works very well, however by default the stream does not return all replies (as per Twitter documentation: By default @replies are only sent from mutual followings. All @replies by followings can be enabled with the replies=all parameter.)

How do I enable the "replies=all" parameter in the Phirehose library?

Thanks a lot,

Filip

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue in a number of places but https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phirehose-users/rHARDfPPyiU shows how it may be possible so I've amended the code and it now works.

To achieve this:

1) Add public $params = null; in Phirehose.php

2) In the connect() function replace $requestParams = array() with $requestParams = is_array($this->params) ? $this->params : array();

3) Before you call consume() put $CLASS->params = array('replies'=>'all','with'=>'user'); in your code. (where class is your class name)

This works for me and I hope it works for you.

Thanks.